# Apply different Color to Image using CSS

Tags: css

I have the following image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbsqC.jpg. If I wanted to change this image so that I could apply different color (to say for example the iphone screen) via CSS properties what would I need to change in the image/how would i go about doing it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You could make the iphone screen transparent on the actual image you store and then use the css property `background-color` to set the background color of the containing element in order to change the color on the screen.